# Which Symmetry class and what kind of topological invariant for $2D -p+ip$?

Tags: condensed-matter, topological-insulators

What kind of topological invariants are there for $2D-p+ip$ topological superconductor and to which symmetry class it belongs to?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is a "p+ip insulator". There is indeed p+ip superconductor, which belongs to the class D and characterized by an integer invariant, the Chern number.

Comment: I meant here superconductor mistakenly I write the insulator instead of superconductor but now I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

All topological insulators can be classified according to their symmetry classes. There is time reversal symmetry ($T$) , charge conjugation symmetry ($C$) and the combination $S=T*C$ symmetry. The $T$ and $C$ symmetries can be either positive or negative, i.e the energy spectrum may change sign under the symmetry operation.

[image: Periodic Table of topological invariants]

The $p+ip$ superconductor is a $p$-vave superconductor and has positive $C$ symmetry and therefore falls into symmetry class $D$. From the table if the follows that it has an $\mathbb Z$ valued topological invariant.